# Сгенерировать html страницу во Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Доброго времени суток!

Я новичек в Python, сейчас изучаю Flask, сильно не бейте. Столкнулся со следующей сложностью: скажем так, из базы данных выводятся список статей, которые сам пользователь добавляет. Так вот, на каждый заголовок статьи должна быть ссылка, куда можно перейти и читать разные комментарии под статьей, куда опять же может добавлять любой пользователь. Сложность в том, как мне сгенерировать эти ссылки, а в частности отдельные html файлы на каждую статью, которые создает пользователь. Я приведу свой код(часть кода я намеренно опускаю, но если потребуется, могу предоставить), как пытался сделать я:

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/art/<articles_id>', methods=['GET', ])
def article_id(articles_id):
    from models import Article
    article = Article.query.filter_by(id=articles_id).first_or_404()
    return render_template('art.html', article=article)

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', ])
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', ])
def index():
    from models import Comment
    from models import Article
    comment = Comment.query.all()
    article = Article.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', comment=comment, article=article)
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{% for articles in article %}
     <h4>Заголовок: <a href="{{ url_for('art', articles_id=articles.id) }}">{{ articles.id }} {{articles.title }}</a> <small>Дата создания: {{ articles.data }}</small></h4  >
     Комментарии:
     <p>{{ articles.first_post }}</p>
     {% for comments in comment %}
         {% if articles.id == comments.article_id %}
         <p class="container"> <mark>{{ comments.post }}</mark>
         <br /><small>{{ comments.data }}</small>    </p>
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**art.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ article.id }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Получаю следующую ошибку: werkzeug.routing.BuildError

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint
>   'app.art' with values ['articles_id']. Did you mean 'article' instead?

Спасибо за ваше терпение и внимание.

Comment: Где код, отвечающий за вывод страницы index.html?

Comment: Добавил код в основной вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему сам с помощью т.н. blueprint.
Если вкратце:

Blueprint’ы во Flask могут пригодиться в случае, если нужно:

- Разделить приложения на набор blueprint’ов. Они идеальны для больших
  приложений; проект должен создать объект приложения, инициализировав
  несколько расширений, и зарегистрировав набор blueprint’ов.
- Зарегистрировать blueprint в приложении по определённом префиксу URL
  и/или в поддомене. Параметры в префиксе URL или поддомене становятся
  обычными аргументами представлений (со значениями по умолчанию) для
  всех функций представлений в blueprint’е.
- Зарегистрировать blueprint несколько раз в приложении с разными
  правилами URL.
- Предоставить фильтры шаблонов, статический файлы, шаблоны и другие
  вспомогательные средства с помощью blueprint’ов. Blueprint не
  является реализацией приложения или функций представлений.
- Зарегистрировать blueprint в приложении в любом из этих случаев при
  инициализации расширения Flask.

Более подробная информация в документации: http://flask-russian-docs.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/blueprints.html на русском языке.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound
import config

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.config.from_object(config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
#ДОБАВИЛ СЮДА
blueprint_page = Blueprint('blueprint_page', __name__, template_folder='templates')

#ИЗМЕНИЛ РОУТЫ
@blueprint_page.route('/article', methods=['POST', ])
def article():
    from models import Article
    from forms import ArticleForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
            art = Article(**form.data)
            db.session.add(art)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Article created!')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            flash('Connot to create an article!')
            flash(str(form.errors))
            return 'Connot to create an article!'


@blueprint_page.route('/art/')
@blueprint_page.route('/art/<id>', methods=['GET', ])
def art(id):
    from models import Article, Comment
    article = Article.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    comment = Comment.query.all()
    try:
         return render_template('art1.html', article=article, comment=comment)
    except TemplateNotFound:
         abort(404)


@blueprint_page.route('/comment', methods=['POST', ])
def comment():
    from models import Comment
    from forms import CommentForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.form)
        if form.validate():
        com = Comment(**form.data)
        db.session.add(com)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Comment added!')
        return redirect(url_for('/art/<id>'))
    else:
        flash('Connot to add a comment!')
        flash(str(form.errors))
        return 'Connot to add a comment!' + str(form.errors)

@blueprint_page.route('/index', methods=['GET', ])
@blueprint_page.route('/', methods=['GET', ])
def index():
    from models import Comment
    from models import Article
    comment = Comment.query.all()
    article = Article.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', comment=comment, article=article)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from models import *
    db.create_all()
    #ДОБАВИЛ СЮДА
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint_page)
    if Comment.query.count() == 0:
        print('База пуста')
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{% for articles in article %}
 <!-- ДОБАВИЛ ТОЧКУ ПЕРЕД URL art -->
 <h4>Заголовок: <a href="{{ url_for('.art', articles_id=articles.id) }}">{{ articles.id }} {{articles.title }}</a> <small>Дата создания: {{ articles.data }}</small></h4  >
 Комментарии:
 <p>{{ articles.first_post }}</p>
 {% for comments in comment %}
     {% if articles.id == comments.article_id %}
     <p class="container"> <mark>{{ comments.post }}</mark>
     <br /><small>{{ comments.data }}</small>    </p>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```